# Convert datetime column to smallint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column called MyYear that is of type datetime. It only stores the year though, so I want to change it to smallint.

When I try to run this:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ALTER COLUMN MyYear smallint
```

I get this error:

> Implicit conversion from data type datetime to smallint is not
>   allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

When I run this:

```
UPDATE MyTable
set MyYear=YEAR(MyYear)
```

It does something funky and sets all the years to 1905.

I am using SQL Server.

Comment: You'll need to first create another column as a `SMALLINT`, update it (`YEAR(MyYear)`) and then drop the first one

Comment: `MyYear` contains a datetime? Ok. Anyway, yeah, when you set a datetime value equal to an integer, it performs a peculiar form of "date math" - it thinks you mean the number of days since zero-date (1900-01-01). Try it: `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 2015);
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 2015, 0);
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 2015, '19000101');`

Comment: @AaronBertrand Very cool, thanks for explaining this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot convert a DATETIME to a SMALLINT, you will need to:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable 
ADD MyActualYear SMALLINT
GO

UPDATE MyTable SET MyActualYear = CAST(YEAR(MyYear) AS SMALLINT)
GO

ALTER TABLE MyTable
DROP COLUMN MyYear
GO

EXEC sp_RENAME 'MyTable.[MyActualYear]' , 'MyYear', 'COLUMN'
GO
```

i.e. add a new temporary column, update it with the value you need, drop the old column and then rename the temp column with the original name.

If you have indexes on this column, you may want to bear in mind any impact this might have.

Comment: This worked great. The only thing I had to change was the syntax of adding the column at the beginning. (just removed the word COLUMN)

Comment: Another thing. I had to remove the brackets around '[MyYear]' at the end otherwise it actually adds those brackets to the column name. If anyone reading this has issues with trying to query on a column name containing brackets, put it in double quotes like "[MyColumn]".